# How to get values of jsonarray on the basis of other jsonarray of keys

Tags: java, json, org.json

Json from server:

```
{ "Data": [ { "Record": [ " d11", "d12" ] }, { "Record": [ " d21", "d22" ] } ], "Keys": [ "Key1", " key2" ]

}
```

I want to retrieve **record** values which are ordered with respect to **keys** `values(key1, key2)`?

The keys in the list supposed to match the keys of the data object..

At server side We have implemented like.. Keys are database columns..and value array(Record) has d11 d12 & d21 d22 which are respective values of columns.. Each record is individual rows... We've used arraylist to ensure insertion order.. Note: we have to avoid putting key:value pair at server side.. Hence Required to Seek to parse this JSON at client side..??

Note: Using `org.json` api only.

Comment: so first record in "Data" field is key1 and second record is key2.

Comment: Nope.. For example: keys is empname, empcode ..actual column names of table...and.. Data array has record array which is actual empnames(d11), empcode(d12) as a individual row.. I have to make a parser which gets thrse records without taking index.. But taking keys in keys array.. I can not fetch the value out using index (obj.getstring(14)) .. since column number can be increased or decreased.. Whereas column names would be promised to be keep unmodified..